# Exclusively Rare Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Solve this *exclusively* rare enigmatic-puzzle.

[image: A set of 6 line images]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to solve this puzzle is to...

> perform an **x-or** (**[exclusive-or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)**, hence the title) operation on all three images in a row, in order to preserve only the line segments that, effectively, appear an odd number of times.

If we do this, we can read a message:

> [image: x-or process in a diagram, producing the answer WELL DONE]
>
>  Here, the segments being removed are highlighted, leaving only the parts that ultimately spell out words (seen in green). The confirmatory message says **WELL DONE**.

Comment: It said the answer was a word hence the tag!

Comment: @PDT Indeed, it just needed retagging.

Comment: It seems too convincing a find to ignore such a conclusion. We will see what the op says.

Comment: I just remembered the "a word or a set of words", my bad... Hopefully it wasn't a major inconvenience...

Comment: It was kind of but dw mistakes happen.

Comment: @SnySmartie Hey, it happens. I find that when setters use the 'word' tag on a visual puzzle it should often be interpreted as 'you want to reduce this image to something you can read', which was the sense you were trying to imply here but isn't _quite_ what it's intended for as per its description. You used it in good faith; I've retagged the question since answering just as a technicality :)

Comment: I won't make the mistake again, but has the community considered changing the description such that the "not a phrase" is emphasized? or is there a tag for a phrase / sentence as solution?

Comment: @SnySmartie Well, it does already say that in the short stub and the first line of the longer description, so I think it's sufficiently indicated as it stands. Consider it just a right of passage to make that error - it happens to all! :)

Comment: @SnySmartie you can state it in the puzzle and say that the answer is a 2 word phrase. Or put ___ ___ underneath the puzzle

Comment: ^ OK IHATE15CHAR

Comment: Under rated puzzle!