# THIS mux be EASY!

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Here's a hint: my favorite color is yellow.

> This MUX be similar to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125364/exclusively-rare-puzzle)!

[image]

> refer to title. Grey(ish) color is actually green.

Comment: Is "Sny" the secret message?

Comment: That's a very good guess considering my pass puzzles but no... The top right is kind of a red herring.

Comment: nope. consider the first hint

Comment: @PDT ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: ^ nah there's no (intended) SAT

Comment: @PDT it's not two four letter words, but this is similar to the last one in that they both use *ybtvp tngrf*. I've also updated the question to reflect that the gray tiles are a bit green just to help people out.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `niche` part? thnx

Comment: Sure it’s just that from a cursory glance at the puzzle it seems like the puzzle is inaccessible to most people since it requires some in-depth specialized knowledge in a particular subject matter to even have a chance of working this puzzle out. People outside of the electrical engineering field would need to spend a lot of time researching before they can have a chance to have a crack at this. I felt the same way about the LOK related puzzle you posted.

Comment: ^ i understand what you mean

Comment: @ SNY even though such a puzzle is one of my pet peeves along with 30 lines of cipher text with little to no hints, it’s not like there is anything wrong with this however just don’t be surprised if it does not get the attention or appreciation you think it deserves.

Comment: Also I would not recommend putting a difficulty rating on your puzzles as such a thing is highly subjective

Comment: A... difficulty rating? When? Oh, title is just flavor text.

Comment: It is not a rating, it is a hint.

Comment: the "EASY" in title is not really a hint either

Comment: The purple cell in r1c3 is a unique color. Is this intended (or is it supposed to match the other purples)?

Comment: It is intended.